# How to sign in to XBox One console from Windows 10

Tags: xbox-one, windows-10

When I try to stream my XBox One it sometimes works (I guess because the Kinect automatically detects and logs me in) but sometimes it doesn't recognize me, and when I try to stream the XBox it says "To continue, sign in on your console using this account."  However, there are times when I cannot see the console any way except via streaming, and cannot log on directly via the console; I need to do it either over the app or via streaming.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have auto sign-in turned on?

- From the Xbox One dashboard, go to the left to open the sidebar
- Scroll down to "Settings"
- Choose "All Settings"
- Choose "Account"
- Choose "Sign-in, Security, and Passkey"
- Set "Instant Sign in" to use your XB1 profile

That said, I actually get this error a lot if I just woke the XB1 up with the Xbox App before trying to stream.  If I give it 15-20 seconds and retry the streaming, it usually works.

Comment: I would perhaps replace "DO you" with "make sure". The asked mentions signing in with Kinect, which is an alternative to auto sign in. Auto sign in would circumnavigate Kinect sign in from the start.

Comment: Seconding your bit about waiting.  Connect, wait half a minute, and then streaming generally works for me.